# JMS server details of a JMS connector encapsulated inside a composite connector

Tags: jms, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a composite source enclosing Multiple jms end connector... I want to know which endpoint within composite source received the message . Note: inbound property does not have end point details. Basically,I want to get the JMS server address ... Or the server address what i have given in the jms endpoint will also be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Got this solution refering to mulesoft documentation:

```
<composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${jms1.queue}"
            connector-ref="jms-connector1" doc:name="JMS1">
            <set-property propertyName="source" value="jms1"></set-property>
        </jms:inbound-endpoint>
        <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="${jms2.queue}"
            connector-ref="jms-connector2" doc:name="JMS2" >
            <set-property propertyName="source" value="jms2"></set-property>
            </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    </composite-source>
```